# Shopify landing_site Order Attribute

Tags: shopify

I have a client that is asking for pretty detailed information about how the `landing_site` attribute of an Order resource works. The [documentation here](http://wiki.shopify.com/Order#landing_site) says that this is set to the first page that someone visits when they come to the shop.

How persistent is this? For example, if someone visits a shop *(entering via the home page, let's say)* then I assume that the `landing_site` will be "/". Let' say that visitor then comes back a day or two later *(this time via a link with a ref parameter)* and visits a product page. Does the `landing_site` attribute update to "/products/sample-product?ref=mytoken"?

If not, how long does this value persist? Is there a way to reset it? If someone at Shopify could explain this, I think it would be something that a lot of app developers would reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Session

If the customer never creates a cart, then cookies are used to keep a reference to this data. `curl -I snowdevil.myshopify.com` can be used to see how persistent these cookies are:

`Set-Cookie: _session_id=...; path=/; HttpOnly`

This header value shows that a session cookies is being stored, which means it will expire when the user closes their browser. It also indicates that only a session_id is stored, so the session data itself is stored on the server.

The data will not be stored indefinitely on the server, because there isn't a way to know when the user closes his browser.  Currently, the session data itself will expire after 1 day.

### Cart

This same value will also get persisted along with any cart data when a product is added to the user's cart.   So, if you look at your cookies for you shop just after adding a product to your cart, you will see there is a separate "cart" cookie which currently expires after 2 weeks. This data will persist this long, even after the user has closed their browser, but will not persist if the user deletes their cookies.

### Disclaimer

A key word to take note of here is "currently", since to my knowledge, Shopify has not made a commitment to keep this data around for a certain amount of time.